# How would you get the velocity in this problem? (and what did I do wrong)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, work, velocity, statics

This problem is supposed to be solved by using the conservation of energy but I do not really know how to solve it that way. 
[image]

Comment: If you can disregard friction the work you do pulling the cord should all be converted to kinetic energy of the collar.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution you have found an acceleration and then used a **constant** acceleration kinematic equation.

In terms of energy think about what $\int F_x\;dx$ might be equal to.

PS Multiply your constant acceleration kinematic equation right through by $\frac 1 2 m$ and you might notice something interesting?